# Swift 4 - Struct static variables not showing values

Tags: swift, struct, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to swift but learning as I go. I have a function to get data from AWS DynamoDB table, using a for..loop. I am capturing field values of table items in struct variables within the loop, but when I call the struct variables in a tableview, it is showing blank array like [] in the log screen in Xcode. Here is the code:

---

```
import Foundation
import SQLite3
import UIKit
import AWSDynamoDB

struct MyVariables {
    static var empDict: [String: String] = [:]
    static var arrayEmployees = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()
}

// This is a class defined to hold various methods to be used throughout the app.
class DatabaseClass: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    // other methods within DatabaseClass
    // ........
    //
    //
    // Scan DynamoDB table for employees
    func scanEmployees () {
        let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
        let scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
        scanExpression.limit = 20

        dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan(Employees.self, expression: scanExpression).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>!) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error as NSError? {
                print("The request failed. Error: \(error)")
            }

            let paginatedOutput = task.result!

            for emp in paginatedOutput.items as! [Employees]  {
                if emp._empid != nil {
                    MyVariables.empDict["Empid"] = emp._empid
                } else {
                    MyVariables.empDict["Empid"] = nil
                }

                if emp._email != nil {
                    MyVariables.empDict["email"] = emp._email
                } else {
                    MyVariables.empDict["email"] = nil
                }

                if emp._firstname != nil {
                    MyVariables.empDict["firstname"] = emp._firstname
                } else {
                    MyVariables.empDict["firstname"] = nil
                }

                if emp._lastname != nil {
                    MyVariables.empDict["lastname"] = emp._lastname
                } else {
                    MyVariables.empDict["lastname"] = nil
                }

                if emp._location != nil {
                    MyVariables.empDict["location"] = emp._location
                } else {
                    MyVariables.empDict["location"] = nil
                }

                if emp._mobile != nil {
                    MyVariables.empDict["mobile"] = emp._mobile
                } else {
                    MyVariables.empDict["mobile"] = nil
                }

                if emp._work != nil {
                    MyVariables.empDict["work"] = emp._work
                } else {
                    MyVariables.empDict["work"] = nil
                }

                if emp._site != nil {
                    MyVariables.empDict["site"] = emp._site
                } else {
                    MyVariables.empDict["site"] = nil
                }

                MyVariables.arrayEmployees.append(MyVariables.empDict)
                //print(MyVariables.arrayEmployees)
            } // for loop

            print ("printing array employees just after for loop")
            print(MyVariables.arrayEmployees)
            // The above print works

            return nil
        })

        // print(MyVariables.arrayEmployees)
        // Above doesn’t print
    }
}
```

Later, I call this DatabaseClass in a tableview as follows:

```
class JsonParseViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let createEmp = DatabaseClass()
        createEmp.scanEmployees()
        print("in JsonParseViewController, calling scan function")
        print(MyVariables.arrayEmployees)
```

When running in simulator, the log file shows the following:

```
in JsonParseViewController, calling scan function
[]
printing array employees just after for loop
[["location": "XXXXXX", "email": "johnSmith1@email.com", "firstname": "John1", "lastname": "Smith1", "mobile": "123-456-7890", "work": "123-456-7890", "Empid": "12345", "site": "KKKKKK"], ["location": "YYYYY", "email": "johnSmith8@email.com", "firstname": "John8", "lastname": "Smith8", "mobile": "123-456-7890", "work": "123-456-7890", "Empid": "12415", "site": "ZZZZZ"], ......etc]]
```

While executing the function scanEmployees, it seems to skip the DynamoDB scan command and returns [] in tableview, but goes to the function somehow and executes the data. It fails to capture the data in struct variables. I have bee trying to fix this for many days.

Comment: `if emp._empid != nil {
                    MyVariables.empDict["Empid"] = emp._empid
                } else {
                    MyVariables.empDict["Empid"] = nil
                }` is equivalent to just `MyVariables.empDict["Empid"]  = emp._empid`

Comment: Thank you, I just fixed the code with suggestion.

Comment: Your `DatabaseClass` has waaaay too much going on. For one, we know it's a class, no need to put that in the name. And your `DatabaseClass` is a `UIViewController`? And also a `UITextFieldDelegate`? There's so much stuff all in one class! Break it down into simpler parts, this spaghetti will consume you

Comment: @Alexander: Sure. I will break it down before I publish for use. Thank you. For now, I am just trying to get through one last step of using DynamoDB data in tableview. Previously the app was working fine with data from local SQLite database

Comment: I read more and learned about asynchronous calls and closures. Thanks for providing a direction and advice on coding practice. I voted this as a good answer, but it is not being being accepted. I have less than 15 reputations

Answer (score 0):

You miss asynchronous call

```
func scanEmployees (completion:@escaping ()-> Void) {

    let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
    let scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
    scanExpression.limit = 20

    dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan(Employees.self, expression: scanExpression).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>!) -> Any? in

        if let error = task.error as NSError? {
            print("The request failed. Error: \(error)")
        }

        let paginatedOutput = task.result! 

            for emp in paginatedOutput.items as! [Employees]  {

                myVariables.empDict["Empid"] = emp._empid
                myVariables.empDict["email"] = emp._email
                myVariables.empDict["firstname"] = emp._firstname
                myVariables.empDict["lastname"] = emp._lastname
                myVariables.empDict["location"] = emp._location
                myVariables.empDict["mobile"] = emp._mobile
                myVariables.empDict["work"] = emp._work
                myVariables.empDict["site"] = emp._site

                MyVariables.arrayEmployees.append(MyVariables.empDict)
                //print(MyVariables.arrayEmployees)

            } // for loop
                print ("printing array employees just after for loop")
                print(MyVariables.arrayEmployees)
              // The above print works

             completion()
             return nil
   } 
 ) 

   // print(MyVariables.arrayEmployees)
   // Above doesn’t print
}
```

//

when calling

```
createEmp.scanEmployees {

       print(MyVariables.arrayEmployees)
}
```

**Note :** I recommend using **SwiftyJson** or **JSONDecoder** intstead of manually parsing the keys

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added completion() as suggested, but the compiler gives error "Missing return in a closure expected to return 'Any?'" . Is it expecting a return statement? Not sure what this return does, even though I understand it is to satisfy the "Any" return value. Also when I changed the call as suggested, I get an error, "Value of type 'JsonParseViewController' has no member 'tableView'. Sorry if these questions are basic, but I am learning. Thanks

Comment: 1- you can return nil as you did after the completion line , as it seems your inner completion has **->Any?** , see edit  2- if you have any table replace it's name or refresh any items you fill from the array

Comment: I added nil and it compiles. As for refreshing array, I couldn't find any swift command. At this time I haven't written the code to display a tableview, I am just trying to make sure data will be coming from the array of dictionaries. So I don't have a tableview to refresh.

Comment: if the data prints inside the completion i edited instead of table , then you get successfully , it's not as you think network requests are asynchronous that means it's not printing serially as the code is written

Comment: I forgot to mention that adding the line **completion()** results in an error **Use of unresolved identifier 'completion'**. So I commented it and just kept return

Comment: I fixed completion() issue. However, calling the function scanEmployees as you suggested, it is still not working. But, I read more and learned about asynchronous calls and closures. Thanks for providing a direction. I voted this as a good answer, but it is not being being accepted. I have less than 15 reputations

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with static memory. I would suggest not to use static values, its a very bad practice. 
The solution could be to create a structure inside The class DatabaseClass. For example var myVariables = MyVariables() and fill it in the same way. Now  You have the option for return it or use it from the DatabaseClass object. I will show the example now how it should look.

```
struct MyVariables {
    var empDict: [String: String] = [:]
    var arrayEmployees = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()
}

// This is a class defined to hold various methods to be used throughout the app.
class DatabaseClass: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    // other methods within DatabaseClass
    // ........
    //
    //
    // Scan DynamoDB table for employees
  public var myVariables = MyVariables()

 func scanEmployees () {
        let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
        let scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
        scanExpression.limit = 20

        dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan(Employees.self, expression: scanExpression).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>!) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error as NSError? {
                print("The request failed. Error: \(error)")
            }

            let paginatedOutput = task.result!

            for emp in paginatedOutput.items as! [Employees]  {
                myVariables.empDict["Empid"] = emp._empid
                myVariables.empDict["email"] = emp._email
                myVariables.empDict["firstname"] = emp._firstname
                myVariables.empDict["lastname"] = emp._lastname
                myVariables.empDict["location"] = emp._location
                myVariables.empDict["mobile"] = emp._mobile
                myVariables.empDict["work"] = emp._work
                myVariables.empDict["site"] = emp._site

                myVariables.arrayEmployees.append(myVariables.empDict)
                //print(myVariables.arrayEmployees)
            } // for loop

            print ("printing array employees just after for loop")
            print(myVariables.arrayEmployees)
            // The above print works

            return nil
        })

        // print(myVariables.arrayEmployees)
        // Above doesn’t print
    }
}

//then use it in this way


    class JsonParseViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let createEmp = DatabaseClass()
            createEmp.scanEmployees()
            print("in JsonParseViewController, calling scan function")
            print(createEmp.myVariables.arrayEmployees)

         }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks @Boris. I changed the code as you suggested in both DatabaseClass as well as the tableView. The code executes, but still returns an empty array first like [] and then it loops through the for loop. log file: in JsonParseViewController, calling scan function
[]
printing array employees just after for loop
[["location": "XXXX", "firstname": "John1", "email": "johnSmith1@email.com", "lastname": "Smith1", "mobile": "123-456-6789", "work": "123-456-6789", "empid": "12345", "site": "YYYYY"],

Comment: in JsonParseViewController, calling scan function
    []
    printing array employees just after for loop
    [["location": "XXXX", "firstname": "John1", "email": "johnSmith1@email.com", "lastname": "Smith1", "mobile": "123-456-6789", "work": "123-456-6789", "empid": "12345", "site": "YYYY"],

Comment: That is strange, did You try to return struct instead of nil? just return myVariables

and remember to change function with return type  like this

func scanEmploys() -> MyVariables

then print after You call function

Comment: I added return and function call, but getting the same result in log file

Comment: func scanEmployees () -> MyVariables {

Comment: return nil            
           } // dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan
         ) // .continueWith
            **return self.myVariables** // added return here
    } // scanEmployees

Comment: I added breakpoints to function scanEmployees. When it is called, it hits the line **dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan** and then goes to the end to **return self.myVariables**.  Log file shows [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2881 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert. Then it goes back to line **if let error = task.error as NSError? {** in code automatically, without my calling the function again and populates the array. By now the call has exited the function in the tableview.

Comment: Seems like a temporary hiccup with SSL_ERROR. Now I am not getting it, but the issue remains.

Comment: As @Sh_Khan suggested, there are things going on in my code with aysynchronous calls. Now I know why the function executes twice. I tried got vote, but I have very few reputations. Thank you